# Proving the uniqueness of the solution to a functional equation involving integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, uniqueness-theorems

Consider the functional equation

$$
g\left(a\right) = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{c(a,h)+f(h)}}{1+e^{c(a,h)+f(h)}}dh
$$

and this holds for all $a$. $g(a)$ and $c(a,h)$ are known functions on a continuous support. Assume that $\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a}\not=0$, $\frac{\partial c(a,h)}{\partial a}\not=0$, and $\frac{\partial c(a,h)}{\partial h}\not=0$.

How can I show that there is one unique $f(h)$ that solves this equation? The ultimate goal is to figure out under what situation will $f(h)$ be uniquely pinned down. So any additional assumptions on $g$ and $c$ that's needed can be added.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not true in this generality (try $c,g$ constant).

Comment: Thanks @ChristianRemling! This is a good catch. I added some assumptions on $c$ and $g$ that ensures variations. Any additional assumptions can be added if they are necessary to deliver uniqueness of $f$.